# I can ping my pi by ip address but not by hostname

Tags: networking, pi-3

I have a Pi3 in my LAN. If I ping it from my Ubuntu machine using its ip address I get an answer. If I do the same using its hostname I get this:

> Destination Host Unreachable

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve the hostname properly?

Comment: If you type `host <hostname>` what IP do you get? Is it different from the IP you are pinging?

Comment: That's weird, it shows me two ip addresses: `pi.fritz.box has address 192.168.178.53` and `pi.fritz.box has address 192.168.178.10`

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tip of Andy Smith I found out there was an old device listed in my fritz.box:

```
$ host pi
pi.fritz.box has address 192.168.178.53
pi.fritz.box has address 192.168.178.10
```

The one with .53 was old.. I removed it from the fritz.box and now it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

For those who read this and do not have the same issue as Rotareti, try installing avahi and samba on your raspberri pi, and it worked like a charm for me.

```
    sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
    sudo apt-get install samba
```

Comment: The issue for me was that windows machines were not being able to resolve host name of the raspberry pi. Samba helped to get host name resolved for windows machines.